# If no records found I see whitespace error PHP Magento 2

Tags: magento2, php, database, adminhtml, phtml

I just used raw sql to get value from table, this is my code.

```
 public function getPaymentUsed(){

    $order = $this->getOrderId();
    $this->_resources = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()
    ->get('Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection');  
    $connection= $this->_resources->getConnection();
    //$sql = "SELECT payment_made FROM `walletsToOrders` WHERE `customer_id` = '$customerid' AND `product_id` = '$prid' ";
    $sql = "SELECT payment_made FROM `walletsToOrders` WHERE `order_id` = '$order' ";
    $result2 =  $connection->fetchall($sql); 
    $real_product = $result2['0'];
    $real_product_price = $real_product['payment_made'];
    return $real_product_price;
    $connection->query($sql);
    }
```

When no record found I see this error.

This is not supposed to arrive.

[image]

But when record found I see my output.

[image]

Comment: If record not found than you have to set the message in condition.

Answer (score 1):

If you're doing a direct SQL query, then you'll need to write your own logic to check if there are no rows returned and output a suitable message.

However, you really don't want to be using direct SQL queries. Magento has a whole abstraction layer which is designed to protect you from having to write such boilerplate code.

Also, Magento relies on various procedures, such as observers and plugins used at code level and triggers, indexes and foreign keys in the database itself to keep track of changes made to different entities (e.g. Prices, Stock, Products, etc). These are all part of a 'belt and braces' safety approach to preserving the integrity of the data in the database. They are also used to trigger other events in the system, e.g. Re-indexing prices.

If you edit the database directly then you are bypassing these features and you may be left with, at best, stale data in your database which is never removed and at worse, you may corrupt your data.

I would replace your direct SQL queries by researching Service Contracts in Magento:
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/extension-dev-guide/service-contracts/service-contracts.html

Also, it is bad practice to use the Object Manager in code. Use Dependency Injection (DI) instead.